# Array to string conversion in a PDO prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is a function to return the username of logged users. However, I can't seem to troubleshoot what's going on and why I'm getting `Notice: Array to string conversion in..` on the first `if()` statement.

```
function getuserfield($field, $link) {
        $query = $link->prepare("SELECT `$field` FROM `users` WHERE `id`= :session_id");
        if ($query->execute(array(':session_id' => $_SESSION['user_id']))) {
                if ($query_result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                        return $query_result;
                }
        }
}
```

As well as that, the whole page becomes unreadable (in terms of encoding). Naturally, I'd use it like so:

```
echo "<p>Greetings, you are logged in as:" . getuserfield('username', $link) . "</p>";
```

Comment: you don't need array(':session_id' => $_SESSION['user_id']), just use execute(array($_SESSION['user_id']))

Comment: `Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined`

Comment: @unixmiah YES YOU DO http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: `execute(array($_SESSION['user_id']))` would return the same notice either ways..

Answer (score 0):

The `Notice: Array to string conversion` indicates that `$_SESSION['user_id]` is an array which I'm trying to access as a string.

```
$query->execute(array(':session_id' => $_SESSION['user_id']['id']))
```

Fixes this. Then calling the function with two `foreach()` statements.